# Is there a Hello World example for the Google Contacts API in Java, C#, Python or Ruby?

Tags: c#, java, ruby, google-api, google-contacts-api

**Question**

Can anyone point me to a step-by-step example which explains how to get started with the Google Contacts API and shows a *complete working* demo?

Preferably in Java, but it can also be in C#, Python or Ruby.

**Goal**

All I want to do is to

1. load an existing contact,
2. add it to a group and
3. save the contact back.

**Problems**

I am pretty much failing on every level.

- Can't get the authentication to work
- Can't find the libraries that contain the classes which are used in the code snippets I found on the Internet
- Can't perform CRUD operations on an existing contact

**Example**

Here is some pseudo-code of what I am looking for.

```
import com.google.contacts.*

public class UpdateContactDemo {

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      GoogleContactsApi g = new GoogleContactsApi("username", "password");
      Contact c = g.get("Bob");
      c.addGroup("Friends");
      g.save(c);
   }
}
```

**What I already did**

Ok, I googled for tutorials, API examples and everything else I could think of -- and failed. I found a bunch of sources like these:

- [Google Contacts API v3](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/)
- [API Directory](https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/directory)
- [Contacts Reference Guide](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/reference)

But non contained an end-to-end example for beginners.

Comment: http://natashatherobot.com/2012/02/03/google-contacts-api-ruby-example/

Comment: If I may make a recommendation... since you are having problems from beginning to end, break this question up into questions for each part? For example, get your issue with authentication handled first and then proceed with the following need. You're asking for a lot of code (or so I think) and it might turn off some people to helping out.

Comment: @SunnyJuneja: Thanks for the recommendation. However, all the snippets I've found so far were in fact bits and pieces tackling one aspect each, but didn't work when I tried to put them together into a demo. That's why I am asking for the "whole thing".

Comment: @apneadiving: Thank you for the link. Had seen it before. Did you get it to run like that?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: This question is really old, and has had no activity. It's too broad, shows now effort, and needs to be closed. "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421)"
and "[How to handle “Explain how this ${code dump} works” questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253894/)"

Answer (score 1):

My approach for C# was this one:

http://nanovazquez.com/2013/01/18/working-with-google-calendar-on-dotnet/

The code can be found on github: [here](https://github.com/nanovazquez/google-calendar-sample/tree/master/GoogleCalendarSample)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  ...
  <appSettings>
    ...
    <!-- GoogleAPI credentials -->
    <add key="ClientId" value="{CLIENT-ID}" />
    <add key="ClientSecret" value="{CLIENT-SECRETD}" />

    <!-- Update the port of the Redirect URI (don't forget to set this value also in the Google API Console) -->
      <add key="RedirectUri" value="http://localhost:{PORT}/Account/GoogleAuthorization" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
  ...
</configuration>
</xml>
```

You can remove the existing Google Calendar api and add Google Contacts Api.

Give this a try.

This has Oauth implementation and works, but the code samples from the code.google.com don't.

Is the best I found so far.

Comment: @Gosu Updated answer with code samples, but will not copy whole project from github here.